# GMs resigning in theoretically lost endgames

Tags: rook-endgame, resigning, queen-endgame

In classical play, do GMs tend to resign in endgames like king+queen vs king+rook where the game can be won by the side with more material in under 50 moves, but only with good play? (I understand queen vs rook is a win in 31 in worst case, barring any immediate captures/checks which make it a draw. A computer can likely draw it out to 50 moves against a human, but another human might not.)

Queen vs rook isn't the only example - think of any pawnless endgame where the fastest forced mate is between 20 and 50 moves long.

On one hand I could see that it might be insulting to continue to play on with such a difference in material, where your opponent will clearly not fall for any skewer tactics and the endgame will be very long and very boring, but on the other hand I see the pragmatism in continuing play as long as there is a non-trivial chance of a draw.

Comment: If there are tricks, they will play. Just like RB vs R endgames are a draw, but actually very often end unpeacefully. Q vs R most also will try. The worst that can happen happens immediately if you resign.

Comment: They will fight while there's hope. If they know a computer can defend it against a human, they will also try themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They may as well try, since Q vs R is extremely difficult to win (even disregarding skewer tactics). The example of RB vs R is a great similar example, as it is a theoretical draw, but **extraordinarily** difficult to draw. There are numerous examples of top grandmasters being unable to convert Q vs R. As to a computer vs human- this was tested in 1978 in a special match between Belle (computer program, had the tablebase so it would play perfectly), and GM Walter Browne. Two positions were played, both with a win in 31 moves. He was unable to convert one but won the other (although barely avoiding the 50 move rule)

Example 1 - [Gelfand-Svidler](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1210725) (two of the greatest players of their time, admittedly a rapid game. Black was pushing but Gelfand held.)

Example 2 - [Morozevich-Jakovenko](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1442203) (Morozevich was a great player, but Jakovenko not so much. Morozevich was pushing, but Jakovenko held with what is known as a rambling rook idea, where a rook is sacrificed and keeps checking so either perpetual check occurs, or the king takes the rook leading to stalemate)

To add more to this- it's quite possible that the side with the queen is in time trouble, which heightens the difficulty of breaking through.

Comment: Note that the tablebase is playing the move that resists the most, not the move that makes it the hardest, so in practice it could even be more difficult

Comment: Eh, id argue that often they'd be the same, but I can certainly see the possibility.

To make it clear as what you mean by hardest and resists:
A tablebase will play the move, that assuming perfect play from both sides, will lead to mate (or conversion into a winning endgame, in this case, winning the rook) in the most (or least, if it's pressing) number of moves. 
Making it hardest for a human player is subtly different from this.

Comment: "not so much" - huh? Jakovenko was ranked number 5 in the world at his peak rating.